# Prevent Word and Excel opening at startup

Tags: macos-highsierra

Every time I restart my mac I find that both Word and Excel open themselves up but with empty documents. If I shut them down and restart - they open again.

Neither app is in my "Users & groups"/"login items" list and the "Open at login" is unchecked for both apps.

I don't want to disable resume for all apps globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I hadn't shut down word fully. I had assumed that if you clicked the cross in the red circle on the word window then that was one and the same thing as shutting down word. But I noticed that the word menu bar was still there! I then found that you could select Word > Quit Word from the menu and then the menu bar would disappear. Then upon restart there was no word window.

It still seems strange that shutting the word window did not shut word altogether.

Answer (score 0):

On the Dock in MacOS, right clicking (or two finger click) on an icon will bring up a menu.  One item is **Options**.  In **Options**, there is "**Open at Login**".  If this is checked, then it will open at login. Unchecking this will disable that option.